# After using require() in WebStorm - unresolved function or method

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, webstorm, intellisense, require

Exported class with `module.exports`

Imported with `require`

WebStorm can't suggest or autocomplete `showAll()` function..

```
const items = await itemClass.showAll();
```

It says:

> Unresolved function or method showAll()

--

*Tested same code with Visual Studio Code, and everything worked without problem.*

Can someone explain why WebStorm not works like it should?
They say it's 'smartest' IDE..

**Node core and coding assistance is enabled**

Comment: I'd bounce this question on the support forums. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367229-WebStorm I'd bet they have a preview release that covers it. If not, they might add it to the roadmap.

Comment: Can you please share a full code sample? The following code works fine for me in WebStorm 2019.3:

```let ItemClass = require('./itemClass');
async function testFunc() {
    let itemClass = new ItemClass();
    const items = await itemClass.showAll()
}
```

Comment: Found similar issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27473

So ill wait for fix..

Answer (score 0):

I solved *(almost)* this issue with additional plugin: Codota

Some sort of helping predictions..